# Is the total mechanical energy of a satellite constant, regardless of its orbital radius?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

If a satellite moves outwards into an orbit that is at a greater distance from the centre of Earth, work has been done. As work is the sum of the change in kinetic energy and gravitational PE, has the total mechanical energy of the satellite changed...or has it remained constant?

When the satellite moves outwards, some of its KE converts into GPE...does this mean - overall, there is no change to the magnitude of total mechanical energy?

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. In elliptical orbits the orbiting body is changing distance from the center of the Earth. So when you say "If a satellite moves outwards into an orbit that is at a greater distance from the centre of Earth" do you really mean that it is moving to a different orbit, or just that it is moving to a different distance within the same orbit?

Comment: Let's assume a circular orbit and that the satellite moves outwards (i.e. increases its distance from centre of Earth). Would its total energy be the same as before?

Comment: What is causing the circular orbit to widen? Some magic hand that is pulling the satellite outward?